# Understanding "inputs" parameter of Bazel "run" action

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am writing a simple Bazel rule that uses `ctx.actions.run`. Unfortunately, I have a hard time understanding `inputs` param of [run](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run) action.

The doc says `inputs` is "a list or depset of the input files of the action". What if my action just runs an executable and passes a few file paths as its arguments ? Suppose I specify the arguments as `arguments` parameter of the `run` action. Do I still need to add these file paths to the `inputs` parameter ? Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `inputs` parameter tells Bazel what files to make available to the executable of the action when Bazel runs it. This parameter is important for a few reasons:

1. It tells Bazel what other actions need to be run to produce the input files for the given action. If you have `Action1 <- Artifact <- Action2`, where `Action2` produces `Artifact`, and `Action1` takes `Artifact` as an input, Bazel knows to run `Action2` before `Action1`.
2. It tells Bazel what files to make available in the action sandbox. Otherwise the action won't be able to find any of its input files.
3. It tells Bazel what files to upload to remote execution workers, if remote execution is being used. Otherwise the file won't be available on the remote machine for the action to read.

The `arguments` parameter of `ctx.actions.run` tells Bazel what the command line for the executable of the action is. If your executable takes flags like `--input` and `--output`, you'd use `arguments` to construct a command line like `--input artifact1 --input artifact2 --output artifact3`.

See this example: https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/master/rules/actions_run/execute.bzl